# Is there any way to use channel default settings while uploading a video/broadcast through the youtube data API?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Would it be possible to use a channel default settings (default video description, etc.) while uploading a video or a broadcast through the YouTube Data V3 API?

Further more, is it possible to fetch the default settings of a channel and maybe update/delete them?

I tried to search for these features in the documentation, but couldn't find anything?
Is there any workaround for this, if it is not possible directly through the YouTube API?

I find that a lot of the features are missing from the provided YouTube API, such as setting a live stream trailer or re-direction.

Apparently YouTube doesn't support fetching or updating a channel's default settings (default video description, comment restrictions, etc.).

Comment: No, the API does not honor the channel defaults.  After uploading via the API, we must use the browser to set the properties that are not available through the API.